# Get the pull request number from CloudBees/Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have a job in CloudBees setup to

> Build pull requests to the repository

It works fine but what I really need is to be able to get the pull request number that triggered the build for use in the execute shell commands field. I know for sure CloudBees/Jenkins is aware of it because the very first line it prints in the Console Output is

> GitHub pull request #4 to owner/repo

But I haven't been able to find a way to easily get access to that #4. I can't find where the console log is stored and it doesn't appear to be an environment variable either. I tried doing an "env" in the execute shell commands field and it wasn't anywhere in there.

How can I get the pull request number from CloudBees/Jenkins for use in the execute shell commands field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.0-beta-3, just released to the update center, defines `$GIT_PR_NUMBER` (among other variables) for this purpose.

Comment: Can you please add a bit more detail here. Name of the plugin. Maybe a link to how to install it. How to access the environment variables. Then I'll definitely accept this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Was this added to a Jenkins plugin or was this a CloudBees thing?

Comment: It is in a Jenkins plugin, but a proprietary one, installed on DEV@cloud machines and also available for Jenkins Enterprise users.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a good way currently. You can try

```
PR=$(curl -s "${BUILD_URL}api/xml?tree=description" | perl -n -e 'print("$1\n") if m{pull/(\d+)"}')
```

Comment: This is what I've been doing so far. `curl -sO $BUILD_URL/consoleText;
PR=$(head -1 consoleText | sed 's/.*pull request #\([0-9]*\) to.*/\1/'); echo "yuck"`

Comment: As far as I know there is no better way at the moment.

Comment: I added a feature request to CloudBees. https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/21823154-Set-the-pull-request-number-as-an-env-var

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using [CloudBees github pull request tester plugin](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Github+Pull+Request+Validation), you can retrieve the pull request number from the build cause (com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.github_pull.GitHubPullRequestCause#number)

Comment: Does not really answer the question as stated.

Comment: So how would I actually use this in the execute shell commands? I searched the CloudBees doc at http://wiki.cloudbees.com/ and could find any reference on how to use GitHubPullRequestCause.